# JSON.deserialize adding time

Tags: json, datetime

```
CalEvent calEvent = (CalEvent) JSON.deserialize(calEventJson,  Technician_Dispatch_Util.CalEvent.class);
System.debug('OGDEBUG TDU calEventJson '+calEventJson);
System.debug('OGDEBUG TDU updateTechnicianCalEvent calEvent.startTime '+ calEvent.startTime + ' calEvent.endTime '+calEvent.endTime);
```

> 15:13:56.110 (110381617)|USER_DEBUG|[185]|DEBUG|OGDEBUG TDU calEventJson {"id":zzzzzzzzzzz","title":"zzzzz New College of zzz","allDay":false,"startTime":"2015-07-27T00:00:00.000","endTime":"2015-07-27T01:00:00.000","ownerId":"zzzzzzzzzz","description":"Perform PM visit as detailed on supplied spreadsheet. Check service office's documentation for equipment list. Contact dispatcher at Help Desk with any questions. For damaged equipment please specify the following:\n\n* Room Name:\n* Manufacturer:\n* Model:\n* Serial No.:\n* Problem: \n\nROOMS TO COVER:\n\nNew College of zz- Sarasota Fl - Carriage House\n\nNew College of zz- Sarasota zz- CHL 0\n\nNew College of zz- Fl - CHL 2z1"}
>
> 15:13:56.110 (110791126)|USER_DEBUG|[186]|DEBUG|OGDEBUG TDU
>   updateTechnicianCalEvent calEvent.startTime 2015-07-27 04:00:00
>   calEvent.endTime 2015-07-27 05:00:00

You can see from the above log output that the json being passed in are correct:

"startTime":"2015-07-27T00:00:00.000"

"endTime":"2015-07-27T01:00:00.000"

However after calling JSON.deserialize time is added onto them (4 hours)

calEvent.startTime 2015-07-27 04:00:00

calEvent.endTime 2015-07-27 05:00:00

Why is this and how can I prevent against it?

FYI
Troubleshooting further I tried something different

```
Map<String, Object> resultsMap = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(calEventJson);
    String startTime = (String)resultsMap.get('startTime');//hack for issue with incorrect time saved
    String endTime = (String)resultsMap.get('endTime');
```

This startTime will have the correct String time
But I cant convert it to Datetime as I get errors

> Invalid date/time: 2015-07-28T00:00:00.000

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) supports the presentation of the Date/Time in both GMT and in the time zone of the User. Is the User you are testing under in a time zone that is 4 hours different from GMT? Your debug output is I think being presented in the timezone of your User rather than in the GMT timezone.

If you change your debug output to use `calEvent.startTime.timeGmt()` and `calEvent.endTime.timeGmt()` I think you will see that the values from the JSON are preserved.

Comment: Thank you very much that does resolve the discrepancy.  However I cannot assign this to my DateTime object as it strips out the date.  How can I get my DateTime object to have my date and time as GMT

Comment: @owengerig The values are held in a DateTime as GMT and offset to the User's timezone in some of the methods and not in others. For example the [getTime](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_getTime) method is GMT based. I don't understand what you mean by "I cannot assign this to my DateTime object".

Comment: So whether im saving them or retrieving them they are DateTime objects.  But its only when i do .timeGmt() that the hours are correct.  if i just read or save the StartDateTime object it reads the +4 hour time.  Basically I need DateTime object with StartDateTime's date and StartDateTime's time get what is returned from timeGmt()

Comment: @owengerig If you really want to deal with dates not date/times then grab the GMT date using [dateGmt](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm#apex_System_Datetime_dateGMT) and just work with the dates. If you use DateTime across your code, and want to stay in GMT,  you will have to be careful to use the various [methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_datetime.htm) ending in "Gmt" everywhere.

Comment: no i want both date and time but i need it without the users timezone coming into play.  thank you though

Answer (score -1):

The below code solved our issue,
After deserialisation the time was getting changed, inorder to have the exact time make use of **Time.newInstance** and pass Hours, minutes and seconds, that will give us the exact time without changing, refer the below logic to implement the same.For example here the input is 12:30 AM then it will be inserted as 12:30 AM

```java
public class businessHourInsert {
   @AuraEnabled
    public static void insertBH(String strBhRecord){        
        try{
            System.debug('Inside the Apex  8 -->'+strBhRecord );
            
            Map<String, object> m =   (Map<String, object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(strBhRecord);
            
            System.debug('BusinessHours>>>>' + m);            
            
            BusinessHours b = new BusinessHours();
            b.Name = (string)m.get('BhName');
            b.SundayStartTime = returnTime((string)(m.get('SundayStart')));
            b.IsActive = true;
            b.IsDefault= false;
            b.TimeZoneSidKey=(string) m.get('TimeZoneKey');            
            b.SundayEndTime = returnTime((string)(m.get('SundayEnd')));            
            System.debug('b---'+b);
            //  System.debug('result.SundayStart--result.SundayEnd-'+result.SundayEnd+'  '+result.SundayStart);            
            Map<String, Object> params = new Map<String, Object>();            
            params.put('InputBusinessHours', b);
            Flow.Interview.Create_Update_BH BhConfigFlow = new Flow.Interview.Create_Update_BH(params);
            BhConfigFlow.start();
  
        }catch(Exception ex){
            throw new AuraHandledException(ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
    
    public static time returnTime(string strTimeVar){
        String timeStr = (string)strTimeVar;
        String defaultTime = '00:00:00';          
        String[] ct = (timeStr != null) ? timeStr.split(':') :defaultTime.split(':');          
        Time t = Time.newInstance(Integer.valueOf(ct[0]), Integer.valueOf(ct[1]), Integer.valueOf(ct[1]), 0);
        return t;        
    }
    
    public class Bhrs {
        public String BhName;
        public Time SundayStart;
        public Time SundayEnd;
        public String TimeZoneKey;
        
    }
}
```

Comment: I've downvoted this because it's a code dump. The explanation is as important as the solution. You should [edit] your answer to include details about _what_ the problem is and _how_ this fixes it.

Comment: I really don't care about your down vote